# Does MVC T4 affect an ASP.NET MVC Application performance?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, code-generation, t4

I just started today to use MVC T4 and I really want to keep using, but there's something that is annoying me.
My application is quite big, so I was wondering whether MVC T4 will harm the performance of my ASP.NET MVC application.
Can I rely on MVC T4?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not worry about the ammount of code that gets generated. The .NET runtime is designed to efficiently crunch through a lot more than what T4MVC generates.

Instead, you should only worry about the impact that the generated syntactic "sugars" have on the runtime behavior of the MVC application. Specifically I'm talking about a case where using a t4mvc pattern might force MVC to use a less efficient way of achieving some functionality. (A hypothetical example of this would be where doing `return View(Views.InvalidOwner);` would be less efficient than `return View("InvalidOwner");`)

After looking through the [samples](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC_doc&referringTitle=T4MVC) page I can't see anything that would stand out as a risk. However, if you are worried you should certainly measure the performance of your application. Take a look at this [video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/mvcConf/mvcConf-2-Steven-Smith-Improving-ASPNET-MVC-Application-Performance) as it provides some great information on how (and even if) to do performance optimization of MVC applications.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's what I was taking about. THANKS

Comment: I have to downvote this.  Your warning somebody that there may be a problem when Gabe down below answers this question very accurately.  T4 creates readonly fields in a class that is held by a static property.  T4 was created with performance in mind and generates code that is nanoseconds slower than a string literal.  Don't want any other reader of this question to come along and think the T4 generated code could possibly be a performance issue.

Comment: Sure, I answered a different aspect of the OP's question. The underlying issue is performance of the application. The red flag that they raised was whether the amount of generated code would have an impact. The short answer is no (first paragraph). The long answer is that performance is not a straightforward subject. T4MVC introduces another layer of abstraction on top of existing MVC APIs, so there's risk (2nd paragraph). Fortunately it doesn't do anything dangerous (3rd paragraph). Instead the OP should focus on other aspects of application performance tuning.

Answer (score 3):

T4 templates are (usually) run at compile-time. So there will not be a runtime cost to your application.

Comment: ok, but the amount of code generated is very big, doesn't matter?

Comment: I suppose it is possible that the generated code is very inefficient - in that case it could hurt performance, but that is not related to T4 itself. But just the fact that there is a lot of code will not be a performance issue.